# Google Compute Instance Web SSH

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

For a Google compute VM, I'd like to block SSH ingress to the world (easy), but still allow console web SSH to the VM.

Does anyone know what IP range the Web SSH comes from? I've tried various published ranges but I can't seem to get the right range for Web console SSH.

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons, IP information is not available right now. As well as, the IP addresses are dynamic, therefore they will change.

One workaround would be to list the IPs in Google netblocks which will have the IP blocks used for ssh from the browser.

```
$ dig -t txt _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com
```

The netblocks are updated whenever IP ranges are added or deleted, as such, the results that you get today might be different than the ones you get in the next few days.

There is a similar feature request open on [GCP issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/35904757), you can refer to it for details.

Answer (score -2):

Google maintains a global infrastructure, which grows dynamically to accommodate increasing demand. As a result, Google servers use a large range of IP addresses, and the addresses often change. The most effective means of finding the current range of Google IP addresses is to query Google's SPF record.

To create an SPF record for your domain, you can simply have the record refer to the Google SPF record for the current list of IP addresses:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

With this method, your domain automatically inherits changes to the Google IP addresses as they happen.

When you need the literal IP addresses for Google servers, start by using one of the common DNS lookup commands (nslookup, dig, host) to retrieve the SPF records for the domain _spf.google.com, like so:

```
nslookup -q=TXT _spf.google.com 8.8.8.8
```

This returns a list of the domains included in Google's SPF record, such as:
_netblocks.google.com, _netblocks2.google.com, _netblocks3.google.com

Now look up the DNS records associated with those domains, one at a time, like so:

```
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks2.google.com 8.8.8.8
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks3.google.com 8.8.8.8
```

The results of these commands contain the current range of addresses.

As mentioned in Digil's answer, this IP ranges will change over time.

You can check this document the topic: https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764?hl=en

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the question

Comment: You can find Google IP ranges by using the aforementioned method.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to find out the exact IP ranges of Cloud Shell.
Quote from the Google documentation:
`"Source IP addresses for browser-based SSH sessions are dynamically allocated by GCP Console and can vary from session to session. For the feature to work, you must allow connections either from any IP address or from Google's IP address range which you can retrieve using public SPF records."`

You can check the link related to quote above here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#ssherror